# Create a Many to Many relationship between ApplicationUser and custom table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, many-to-many

I am a newbie to building website's in asp.net mvc5. I followed some tutorials and build my first website based on a existing database, so that's why i choose for database first approach.

Now I want to create with many to many relationship between the applicationuser object with my resource object.

from db point of view:

AspNetUsers <-> ApplicationUserResources <-> Resource

Which steps do I need to follow when using a database first approach to archive this relationship.

Wesley

Comment: this is far too broad, please read the [help]

Comment: what do you mean about to broad? I want to create a many to many relationship with ApplicationUser object.

Comment: [See here for what I mean](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Also read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can add any navigation props in your ApplicationUser class as well as in any other EF Entity

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources{ get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser > ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```